# Revisiting auto-pst-pdf Fundamental Problem (<jobname>-pics.pdf not created)

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, auto-pst-pdf

The code provided as an answer on [this post](/questions/61201/conflict-between-packages-auto-pst-pdf-and-minted) used to work. To ease things, I reproduce it here, only in a more condensed form since I'm interested just in the `PSTricks` part -- the `minted` part working alright.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{minted}
  \usemintedstyle{friendly}
  \newminted{latex}{linenos=true,mathescape}
\else
  \usepackage{pstricks-add}
\fi
\pagestyle{empty}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{postscript}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
\psframe*(0,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{postscript}

and now the minted part: (no problem here, I've just deleted it)

\end{document}
```

What I get is a fine `pdfLaTeX -shell-escape` compilation, but no picture and the dreaded (by me, at least) message `"Creation of <jobname>-autopp.pdf failed"`. Is there somebody who can reproduce this behavior or suggest what's been going on? I'm using an updated (about two weeks old) (semi-)full installation of MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows XP.

EDIT: In accordance with Joseph Wright's suggestion to issue the `\listfiles` command, I append next the list appearing in my `.log` file:

```
 *File List*
 memoir.cls    2011/03/06 v3.6j configurable book, report, article document class
 ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifetex.sty    2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
 mem12.clo    2010/10/19 v0.4b memoir class 12pt size option
 mempatch.sty    2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
 auto-pst-pdf.sty    2009/04/26 v0.6 Wrapper for pst-pdf
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
 ifplatform.sty    2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system
 pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 catchfile.sty    2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
 etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 pst-pdf.sty    2008/10/09 v1.1v PS graphics for pdfLaTeX (RN,HjG)
 graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
 graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
 pstricks.sty    2013/05/22 v0.57 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
 pstricks.tex    2013/07/09 v2.45 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
 pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 pst-fp.tex    2013/07/09 v2.45 `PST-fp' (hv)
 xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
 color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 preview.sty    2010/02/14 11.86 (AUCTeX/preview-latex)
 dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
 environ.sty    2013/04/01 v0.3 A new environment syntax
 trimspaces.sty    2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
 minted.sty    2011/01/04 v1.7 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX
 fancyvrb.sty    2008/02/07
float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
Tryout.pyg
supp-pdf.mkii
***********
```

Comment: Could you edit in the *File list* you get in the `.log` file if you use `\listfiles` in the input? This seems to be 'works for me' With TeX Live 2013, Win7.

Comment: @JosephWright: Done.

Comment: Works fine for me (miktex 2.9). In most cases pdfcrop is the problem so try `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}`.

Comment: I also have no problems on Win 7, MikTeX 2.9, TeXnicCenter 2

Comment: I'm updating again my installation and will try as soon as the process is over.

Comment: I've updated my installation and now it works fine. Not a full reinstall, but just an update, which I had done a few weeks ago. One of those arcanes... So maybe this question should be closed as non-constructive, or too localized? Thanks to everybody involved.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue fixed by updating to the current releases of the packages involved.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: Fine. I'm not sure what the right thing to do is: maybe deleting or closing it?